# How do I put SAFEARRAY (array of bytes) to HTML Hidden field

Tags: javascript, c++, html, com, atl

I'd like to get array of bytes from active-x component, store that in html-form input hidden field and then pass it to server via form-submit. How can I do that?

MIDL:

```
HRESULT Data([out, retval] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) *pArray);
```

C++/ATL

```
STDMETHODIMP MyActiveX::get_Data(SAFEARRAY **pArray)
{
    CComSafeArray<BYTE> arr;    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        CComVariant a;
        a = (BYTE)i;
        arr.Add(a);
    }

    arr.CopyTo(pArray);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Javascript:

```
  $("#hiddenField").val(myActiveX.Data);
```

Browser tells me: type mismatch

Comment: I know nothing about activceX but i would suggest something like a `.toString()` on the data.

Comment: Sorry, @James, toString() returns "Object Object" to me

Comment: That `toString()` returns "Object Object" indicates that `toString()` is not implemented on your object in a meaningful way.  See my answer.

Comment: Use Firebug in Firefox to identify the type of the object and what members it has. I'm guessing it could be something like an array of integers.

Comment: @Andrew I mean your own version of it for this object.

Comment: @Andrew Florko: Any progress with this question? Have you been able to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not familiar with your exact situation, I have seen some similar situations before.

You are correct to put your data in a field using `$('#hiddenField')`.  If you've put a `name` attribute on that field so that it becomes part of the HTTP submit, that part is good.

As for `myActiveX.Data`, I imagine that this is some sort of JavaScript object.  Remember that only a string can be put into an HTML input; it does not hold binary data.

What I would do is put a breakpoint before `$("#hiddenField").val(myActiveX.Data);`
.  Use the `debugger` keyword if you're not familiar with it.  Run the code in your debugger and look at the structure of the value of `myActiveX.Data`.  It probably has some sort of wrapper field.

Alternatively, if you don't have access to a good JavaScript debugger, try the following"

```
for(x in myActiveX.Data)
 alert(x + ": " + myActiveX.Data[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the C++ code is the server side code.

The best way to handle this is to serialise the SAFEARRAY. From there you can handle it in two ways.

Firstly, the serialisation. I've looked at MSDN and I think using [LPSAFEARRAY_Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644537.aspx) and [LPSAFEARRAY_Unmarshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644390.aspx) (with an optional `IDispatch` or `IUnknown` IID to specify the type, but the documentation doesn't say how it's used) or [LPSAFEARRAY_UserMarshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644398.aspx) and [LPSAFEARRAY_UserUnmarshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644503.aspx) to convert the SAFEARRAY to/from a serialised format.

Secondly, handling the data transfer.

- Option 1: Save the serialised data on the server side and put a token representing the saved file into the hidden field.
- Option 2: Use Hex, Base64, etc. to encode the data into a printable format and putting that data into the hidden field.

Either way, when you need to get the data back, just de-serialise it with the matching function.